# What could possibly be a Mysql database structure for an web app say like Flurry

Tags: mysql, database

Simply say, I'm working on a web App say like Flurry (http://www.flurry.com/), that would communicate with a Smartphone App trough API.

Right now I'm designing the database structure, and I guess with my lack of knowledge or best practice on this topics, I'm wondering if I'm on the right track.

What I'm doing is as follow(please don't pay so much attention to naming):

**Web App**
Admin Panel allowing web app user registration/login, add App and monitor different kind of information from the Smartphone App Client users.
web app users could be company or individual developer.

**WebAppAdminDB**
Database that would store information regarding the web app users as well as app that created by each of them

**WebAppAdminDB > Users**
Table that store all web app users info (email, password, pic, settings)

**WebAppAdminDB > App**
Table that contain list of App create by all web app users (App name, AppID, AppKey...etc). Along with that there would be a field referencing the web app user who created this app.

I was thinking to create another database that would contain information about Smartphone app users instead to have that in the same database of the WebApp.
the thing is I don't know if it should be a database for each app created or just one database that would regroup all user of all app.

Should the DB be structured as follow:
ClientDB with table Users including rows
  User1, AppID1, infos...etc
  User2, AppID1, infos...etc
  User3, AppID5, infos...etc
  User4, AppID3, infos...etc
  ...
  UserN, AppID, infos...etc

OR
Maybe should I have a 'AppID_name_DB' for each App created (by any web app users) and include Smartphone users info as follow:

AppID_1_DB with table Users including rows
  User1, infos...etc
  ...
  UserN, infos...etc
.
.
.
AppID_N_DB with table Users including rows
  User1, infos...etc
  ...
  UserN, infos...etc

Is there any best practices that professional on those topics would point me at?
Any comment or thoughts would be appreciate, as I'm trying improve my understanding of Database / web app architecture.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A question like this is probably better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I see. I don't ask so many questions on Stackoverflow, so I was not careful. Should I close this discussion/question?

Comment: You can't delete this now since someone posted an answer.

Comment: Understood. Anyway, will post on programmers.stackexchange.com as you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are saying about typical fact table in OLAP.

In a general manner of relational database modeling, a single fact table with index would be enough. If each App has its own table, managing database and handling data will be more complicated.

Nevertheless, if you really need to do so, I suggest creating a view (like VW_AppID_name_DB) on the fact table instead.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I don't really want to create a table for each app neither, so I will probably end by something more straightforward.